# Multiline latex equation

Tags: math-mode, equations, line-breaking

I have latex equations within `\[ ... \]` commands. Some of them doesn't fit page width and they have newline command `\\` inside. I tried to surround these equations with `gather*` environment which works good but I can't use this environment directly.

I just need to add support for multiline equations to `\[ ... \]` commands. Is this possible? Thanks.

Comment: Why can't you use `gather*`?

Comment: I can't use it directly because latex content isn't written by me. It's written for MathJax which supports multiline equations by default so authors of this latex content can write them simply using `\[` and `\]`.

Comment: is it the case that you can't intervene manually at all?  if so, that is very bad.  (i think i need to learn more about how mathjax handles things like this ...  it's not acceptable to require this kind of change to latex/amsmath.)

Comment: mathjax can be configured to support the ams alignments without wrapping them in `\[\]` Putting them in math was required in early versions but was never tex syntax.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because based on a misunderstanding of mathjax requirements (can use ams alignments as in tex)